# conditional ssl_client_verify in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

I have two different (source) URLs, "ACME01" URL sends client certificate and other "ACME02" doesnt send client certificate (say old version of deployment).

And in the destination server, we have this

```
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/client-cert/ca.crt;
ssl_verify_client optional;
```

Request coming from ACME02  should have `ssl_client_verify - NONE`  and request coming from ACME01 should have `ssl_client_verify - SUCCESS`.

Question mark, in order to implement backward compatibility under "location" line in destination server, how do we grant the traffic for both  using "if" condition? Some recommendation/suggestion is appreciated.